# Pandas: query + mul + groupby + cumsum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

My dataframe looks like this:

| CUST_NO | ORDER_AMOUNT | PAYT_CODE | IS_PAYMENT_SUCCESSFUL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 50 | OR | 1 |
| 001 | 20 | IC | 0 |
| 001 | 10 | IC | 1 |
| 002 | 55 | IC | 1 |
| 002 | 300 | MR | 1 |
| 002 | 215 | MR | 0 |

I want to know the total amount a customer has successfully paid all-time, specifically from the payment codes `'OR', 'IC'`. The dataframe is sorted and indexed by order date.
The expected output is shown in the `CUMSUM_OR_IC_SUCCESSFUL` column:

| CUST_NO | ORDER_AMOUNT | PAYT_CODE | IS_PAYMENT_SUCCESSFUL | CUMSUM_OR_IC_SUCCESSFUL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 50 | OR | 1 | 0 |
| 001 | 20 | IC | 0 | 50 |
| 001 | 10 | IC | 1 | 50 |
| 002 | 55 | IC | 1 | 0 |
| 002 | 300 | MR | 1 | 55 |
| 002 | 215 | MR | 0 | 55 |

I already have some code that should work, but it just keeps running until the kernel crashes.

```
df["CUMSUM_OR_IC_SUCCESSFUL "] = (df.query("PAYT_CODE == ('OR', 'IC')")["IS_PAYMENT_SUCCESSFUL"].mul(df["ORDER_AMOUNT"])
                                                                    .groupby(df["CUST_NO"])
                                                                    .transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift().fillna(0))
                                            )
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: should the result at the third row be 50 as the is_payment_succesful is 0 at the previous row?

Comment: and what is the variable `query_df`?

Comment: Where is the `70` come from? `50*1+20*0+10*1=60`

Comment: There were some errors in my question. The variable `query_df` should be just `df`, and there was supposed to be no 70 at row 3, just 50.

Comment: @yalexx so are you prepared to ignore the number `10` in row 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, this one worked:

```
df["CUMSUM_GUARANTEED_SUCCESSFUL"] = df["ORDER_AMOUNT"].mul(df["PAYMENT_SUCCESSFUL"]).mul(df["PAYT_CODE"].isin(['IC', 'OC'])).groupby(df["CUST_NO"]).transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift().fillna(0))}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

```py
agg = df.groupby("CUST_NO").apply(lambda x:(x["ORDER_AMOUNT"] * x["PAYT_CODE"].isin(["IC", "OR"]) * x["IS_PAYMENT_SUCCESSFUL"]).cumsum())
df["CUMSUM_OR_IC_SUCCESSFUL"] = agg.to_numpy()
```

### Output

Although not as different as your expectations, I still guess that your output table has a little mistake.
If you want to `shift` `CUMSUM_OR_IC_SUCCESSFUL` with one position, use `agg.shift().to_numpy()`

```
   CUST_NO  ORDER_AMOUNT  ... IS_PAYMENT_SUCCESSFUL  CUMSUM_OR_IC_SUCCESSFUL
0        1            50  ...                     1                       50
1        1            20  ...                     0                       50
2        1            10  ...                     1                       60
3        2            55  ...                     1                       55
4        2           300  ...                     1                       55
5        2           215  ...                     0                       55
```

### Explanation

`apply` will run for each `group`

Comment: Thanks but this one returned some weird results, not sure why

Comment: @yalexx Example?